# determine integral with special measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu: \mathscr B(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R, \mu(A)=\#(\mathbb N \cap A)$. (This means $\mu(A)$ is the number of natural numbers of $A$)
Determine $\int_\mathbb R \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu$.
How can I determine this? I already showed that $\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: $\int_\mathbb{R} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu = +\infty$. However the arguments in the accepted answer are incorrect (see chat).

Comment: Here is a simple and correct way to determine $\int_\mathbb{R} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu$. Note that $\int_\mathbb{R} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{[n,n+1)} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for all $x \in [n,n+1)$, $\lfloor x \rfloor =n $ e also $\mu([n,n+1)) = 1$. So,$\int_{[n,n+1)} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu = n$. So, $\int_\mathbb{R} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{[n,n+1)} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu =  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n = +\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I hope you have proved that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is Borel-measurable function. Afterwards, notice that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-n}^{n} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu$ (1). Then, we observe that in each $[-n,n]$ interval, floor function is a simple function. It takes all the natural values from $-n$ to $n$. (Let's consider that $0\in{\mathbb{N}}$). Thus, $\int\limits_{-n}^{n} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu=\sum\limits_{i=-n}^{n} i\mu([-n,n])$. It is easy to observe that $\mu([-n,n])=2n+1$ or $\mu([-n,n])=2n$ (if we exclude $0$ from $\mathbb{N}$.) Hence, $\int\limits_{-n}^{n} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu= \sum\limits_{i=-n}^{n} i(2n+1)=(2n+1)^2$. From (1), we conclude that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \lfloor x \rfloor d\mu = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} (2n+1)^{2}=+\infty$ and the integral diverges.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138291/discussion-on-answer-by-galoisth-determine-integral-with-special-measure).